# efficient way to resize numpy or dataset?

Tags: python, numpy, h5py

I want to understand the effect of `resize()` function on `numpy` array vs. an `h5py dataset`. In my application, I am reading a text file line by line and then after parsing the data, write into an `hdf5` file. What would be a good approach to implement this. Should I add each new row into a `numpy` array and keep resizing *(increasing the axis)* for numpy array *(eventually writing the complete numpy array into h5py dataset)* or should I just add each new row data into `h5py dataset` directly and thus resizing the `h5py dataset` in memory. How does `resize()` function affects the performance if we keep resizing after each row? Or should I resize after every 100 or 1000 rows?

There can be around 200,000 lines in each dataset.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: those who don't know about h5py, could you please comment on numpy performance for resizing eachtime after adding a new row?

Comment: Why not use `np.fromfile` to read the entire file as a numpy array to begin with?  You won't get a whole lot faster ...

Comment: text file is a raw data which i need to parse and then convert into a specific format. file size is around 2 GB. i am processing data byte by byte.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think resize() will copy all the data in the array, it's slow if you call it repeatly.

If you want to append data into the array continuously, you can create a large array first, and use index to copy data into it.

Or you can use array object from array module, it's a dynamic array that behaves like list. after append all the data into array object, you can convert it to ndarray. Here is an example:

```
import array
import numpy as np
a = array.array("d")
a.extend([0,1,2])
a.extend([3,4,5])
b = np.frombuffer(a, np.float).reshape(-1, 3)
```

Answer (score 2):

NumPy arrays are not designed to be resized. It's doable, but wasteful in terms of memory (because you need to create a second array larger than your first one, then fill it with your data... That's two arrays you have to keep) and of course in terms of time (creating the temporary array).
You'd be better off starting with lists (or regular arrays, as suggested by @HYRY), then convert to ndarrays when you have a chunk big enough. 
The question is, when do you need to do the conversion ?

Comment: thanks @pierre. I have implemented HYRY's solution. this array is storing the converted data only. i need to write this data to hdf5 files. I guess its similar to hdf5 files where i should not be writing data row by row. I will first read the complete files and parse the data into array object and then write that object into the hdf5 file. Thanks.